# A very simplified version of histogran calculation, still gives errors

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Im still trying to understand histogram calculation. As I stated in my other post i was having trouble understanding the official tutorial and the one in my book.

The tutorial I am tanking about is located here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html

I was really having trouble reading that, especially the part where the calculated histograms were being drawn. It involves splitting, normalizations, values given whithout any explanation such as the values of hist_w and hist_h, and the all complicated line function.

So I decided to just write what I learnt in a simple manner just to see the working of a histogram and see how it goes. This is what I wrote:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Mat src, dst, final;

src = imread("c:\\car.jpg", 0);

int histsize = 256;
float range[] = {0, 256};
const float* histrange = { range };

bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

calcHist(&src, 1, 0, Mat(), dst, 1, &histsize, &histrange, uniform, accumulate);

for(int h= 0; h<histsize; h++)
{
    float value = dst.at<float>(h);

    line(final, Point(h,(histsize-1)), Point(h, value), Scalar(0,0,0));
}

namedWindow("meh",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("meh", final);
waitKey(0);


return 0;
```

}

The images is loaded in grayscale so there is no need for splitting. And simply the calcHist was applied and the line function was used to draw it.

But it gives an unhandled exception error when calling. I believe it has to be because of my over simplified line function. As in the tutorial online the calculation for the coordinates is way too complex.

But I thought this should work, let me explain. in the first loop h will be 0, so the coordinates will be `(0,255) and (0,[value of histogram at 0])`, similarly on second loop the coordinates will be `(1,255) and (1,[value of histogram at 0])` and so on..

This is what in theory the histogram is right. It should work.. why is it not?

edit:: it breaks at `imshow("meh", final);`

Comment: Does it crash in `calcHist()`, or does it crash in `line()`?

Comment: It crashes on ``imshow("meh", final);``

Comment: Does it also crash if you do `imshow("meh", src);`?

Comment: no, I tried that. It works on src, and even dst. But final breaks it